# dynamic css not working on checkbox change vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to dynamically change the `css` of some text in a `span` when a `checkbox` is `checked` using `v-on:change` but it is not changing and I can't figure out why.

The `boolean` data property "bolden" does change on-click (checked with console.log) but the class does not. the class does not even appear in the 'span' element tag when checked on devtools in chrome

here is a jsfiddle link of a piece of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/rL0fzv7s/

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="checkbox" value="food" v-model="blog.categories" v-on:change="bolden = !bolden">
  <span v-bind:class="bold">food</span>
</div>
.bold {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: red;
}
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    bolden: false,
    blog: {
      title: "",
      content: "",
      categories: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    bold: function() {
      return {
        bolden: this.bolden
      };
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your styles are not showing even though the value of `bolden` is changed is that the class name that you are using is `.bold` but the class name that you are returning from the computed property is called `.bolden`.

Change your computed `bold` functions's return value to the following:

```
computed: {
  bold: function() {
    return {
      bold: this.bolden // class
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you greatly for the help! works perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

You should return `bold` class while `this.bolden` true. below is the corrected code. Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/62mewykL/

```
 bold: function() {
          return {
            bold: this.bolden
          };
        }
```

OR

Simply use `v-bind:class="{'bold' : this.bolden}"` in HTML

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using the inline method for learning purposes but the first eg works so thank you greatly!